# Getting object data from AngularJS $resource request, without the resource functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I'm currently trying to export a CSV of items from an Angular $resource request in my controller `Items.query()` - the $resource requests return an array of Angular resource objects which have extra function properties like so:

```
Resource {_id: "540432e0f2ef60b1284d9187", example: "Stuff", __proto__: Resource $delete: function (params, success....
```

So on my CSV I get all the data I want but with extra messy columns from this __proto__ property. What would be the best way of separating out the data I need? Would I use a $promise.then() added to the query() and inside that modify the objects to be safe for CSV output?
Or would I add a function to the service itself for doing so? This is the api service:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).factory('Items', ['$resource', function($resource) {  
  return $resource('api/items/:id', {id: '@_id' }, {  
    update: {
      method: 'PUT'
    }
  });
}]);
```

All the resources also have a property of `__v: 0` but this doesn't appear in the CSV export, can someone explain why this isn't exported but the proto resource functions are?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you define the list of properties you want to export to CSV? That's the only way to guarantee that all the CSV entries have the same information.

Comment: Hi @bmleite, so you mean just create a new object for each one with the properties I'm interested in?
Like,  
    `var objArr;  
    Label.query().$promise.then(function(data){  
      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {  
        objArr[i]._id = data[i].id;  
        objArr[i].name = data[i].name;  
        etc. etc. etc.`

Answer (score 0):

Following @bmleite's advice I just created a new array using the resource object's data picking the properties I want. Something like:

```
Label.query().$promise.then(function(data) {
  var csvArray = [];
  for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
    csvArray[i] = {
      _id: data[i]._id,
      example: data[i].example,
      ......
    };
  }
});
```